# jQuery Validation - adding required fields dynamically via ajax in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use jQuery validation on a form in MVC2. I'm using the: **MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js** from the futures project.

When the form first loads it is for the RepresentativeViewModel and there are three fields that are validated against. The validation works perfectly for them.

A user may click on a link which loads in 3 additional required fields via an Ajax represented by the class ContactViewModel.

I've got it working so that the MVC framework sends back the right **window.mvcClientValidationMetadata** data to the browser and the **__MVC_EnableClientValidation** and **__MVC_CreateValidationOptions** functions are being called for the newly added fields.

However when the submit button is pressed only the first 3 fields are being validated against.

The models I'm using are:

```
public class RepresentativeViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Telephone is required")]
    public string Telephone { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Website is required")]
    public string Website { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ContactViewModel> ContactList { get; set; }
}

public class ContactViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int RepresentativeId { get; set; }
    public RepresentativeViewModel Representative { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="First Name is required")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Job is required")]
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Through a bit of debugging I found this in jquery.validate:

```
// check if a validator for this form was already created
var validator = $.data(this[0], 'validator');
if ( validator ) {
    return validator;
}
```

it seems that after I load the extra fields in via ajax, the validator associated with the form will never be updated.  If I comment out the line:

```
    return validator;
```

then only the new fields get validated.

How do I get both the original and the new fields to be validated when the user clicks on submit?

Comment: Could you post the code you use to declare de validation?

Comment: Hey Lobsterm, I added in the code for the models I'm using

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
      $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);
    });
```